# How to hide other section of chartjs on click of lengend

Tags: angular, chart.js

In ChartJS if we click on legend, then the section on which we click that will get disappear. Can this be reversed? Like if we click on legend then apart from that section all other section in chart should get disappear. Is this possible? Can anyone suggest any solution on this.I have to do this on angular 2+. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this ChartJS wrapper: [ng2-charts](https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/). It works great on latest Angular 2+, I used it on Angular 5. This wrapper offers you a chartClick for the directive so you can link it with a function in your code. With no more info about what you are trying to do I would suggest you look at this and maybe work using that event object.

```
(chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"
```

Comment: Antonio, that will give me the element event, Even though i will find the legend clicked. but how to hide the rest of the section apart from that on which it got clicked, i can do it via destroy and rebuild chart, which will make it ugly, so is there any option to hide other element?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to set div around it and set *ngif option and click event.

Your chart